# Building LLVM toolchain Stops midway through

Tags: llvm, riscv, ara

So I am atempting to build the ARA-RISCV build and it requires a RISC-V LLVM toolchain and they give you a "make toolchain-llvm" command and it starts off ok but midway through the build around 2500/3500 it stops and the terminal closes without pointing out any error while it builds.
The command that are used are the ones below:

```
mkdir -p /.../rvv/install/riscv-llvm
cd /.../rvv/toolchain/riscv-llvm && rm -rf build && mkdir -p build && cd build && \
cmake -G Ninja  \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/alex/Documents/Project/rvv/install/riscv-llvm \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ \
-DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=riscv64-unknown-elf \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="RISCV" \
../llvm

cd /.../rvv/toolchain/riscv-llvm && \
cmake --build build --target install
```

After everything the build is incomplete and a lot of files have not been downloaded.I dont know what is causing this can anybody help?

Please and thank you.

EDIT:It worked by adding -j8 to the last instruction aka

```
cmake --build build --target install -j8
```

Comment: If ninja -j1 works, the problem was lack of RAM.

Comment: Would it help if I increase the swap memory?

Comment: No. The memory's really used, not just allocated. Linking needs up to about 6GB, so use `cmake -DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=1` if you have 8GB, =2 if you have 16GB, =5 if you have 32GB.

Comment: I have 8gb of ram but the cmake -DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=1 command still didnt work.It went a little bit higher on 2650/3500 but it again stopped and closed.

Comment: Does ninja -j1 work?

Comment: Do i replace the  cmake -G Ninja with the ninja -j1?